# Not get proper URL when deploy code in production using rest API in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, rest, salesforce-lightning

Am using rest api for get some data .. I use same code in sandbox it work well.. but when i use this code in production it will show error.. i will attach some image for particular error anyone can please resolve it..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUQa8.png)

Comment: That's way too little info. How do you call this API. Named credential? What authentication. Maybe you need to configure some username password in the named credential, maybe it uses certificate but for accessing production version of this API you need different certificate... You'd have to ask owners of this service for help debugging.

Comment: We don't use any auth .. we directly get data